# Import does not look into pythonpath when importing personal modules

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, pythonpath

I have build my own package named "XXX" on my computer by setting a `__init__.py` file in the `C:\path\to\module\XXX` folder, which contain my python script. Then I added `C:\path\to\module\XXX` to my pythonpath manually. When I run python on a cmd prompt and try to import the module it fails. When I print `sys.path`, it contains `C:\path\to\module\XXX`. If I try to load some other personnal modules, the same problem occures but when I try to load module not of my own, installed with `pip` (i.e. `numpy`) it works perfectly. So my guess is that for some reason python is not looking into my pythonpath anymore to load module.

I am using anaconda with python 3.6.5 with a vitual environnement on windows 7. Python is installed with anaconda via conda-forge repo.

I have tested this issue with multiple approach, first by running the script below with Pycharm and then with Spider. Then I used anaconda prompt to run the commands manualy activating my virtual environnement first. Finally I ran the commands on a DOS prompt with python. Whatever the way, the results where the same. This error just occured after installing fbprohete in my virtual environnement. Before that I was able to import my modules. I tried to remove that module but the problem remains the same. A lot of mess append during the installation of fbprohet. After the installation I ran a conda clean command to clean the environnement but it didn't help. I suspect that something is corrupted now but I would like to avoid reinstalling everything. If you have an idea where to look, which module in particular should be corrupted, I will be glad to know more about it.

```
 import sys

 sys.path

['', 'C:\path\to\module\XXX', ...]

 import XXX

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XXX'
```

Whith the script above, I expect the module to be loaded without error since the path to the package is in the pythonpath and the `__init__.py` is in the folder `C:\path\to\module\XXX`

Thanks!

Comment: `sys.path` contains directories that python looks **into** to search for the module. Do you have `C:\path\to\module\XXX\XXX.py` or `C:\path\to\module\XXX\XXX\__init__.py` on your system? If not you probably want to have `C:\path\to\module` and **not** `C:\path\to\module\XXX` in `sys.path`

Comment: Yes your are right. I replaced `C:\path\to\module\XXX` by `C:\path\to\module` and it worked. It was a bit silly of me, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

So it was a bit silly actually. I should have replaced `C:\path\to\module\XXX` by `C:\path\to\module` in the pythonpath because `__ini__.py` is in the `C:\path\to\module\XXX` folder. Thanks Giacomo Alzetta for your comment.